# "Failed to create server socket" when running pub build on OpenShift with Dart

Tags: dart, openshift

Trying to get Dart running on OpenShift via a DIY cartridge. I have the binaries built for RHEL6 and they're running (the dart VM itself works just fine). In my hooks, however, I am attempting to `pub build` during the build phase, naturally, to compile the Javascript, etc. `pub get` works fine, but running `pub build` results in an error. Here is the stack trace:

```
FINE: Pub 1.5.1
IO  : Deleting directory build.
FINE: Loaded package graph.
FINE: Clean up system cache temp directory /var/lib/openshift/(snip)/app-root/runtime/repo/_temp.
ERR : Failed to create server socket (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 0
FINE: Exception type: SocketException
FINE: dart:io                                                                                   HttpServer.bind
    | /usr/local/sandbox/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/barback/barback_server.dart 49      BarbackServer.bind
    | /usr/local/sandbox/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/barback/asset_environment.dart 395  AssetEnvironment._load
    | /usr/local/sandbox/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/barback/asset_environment.dart 70   AssetEnvironment.create.<fn>
    | dart:isolate                                                                              _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage
    | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
    | dart:async                                                                               _Future.then
    | /usr/local/sandbox/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/barback/asset_environment.dart 62  AssetEnvironment.create
    | /usr/local/sandbox/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/command/build.dart 56              BuildCommand.onRunTransformerCommand
    | /usr/local/sandbox/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/command/barback.dart 60            onRun
    | dart:async                                                                               Future.Future.sync
    | /usr/local/sandbox/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/utils.dart 90                      syncFuture
    | /usr/local/sandbox/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/command.dart 178                   PubCommand.run
    | /usr/local/sandbox/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/bin/pub.dart 198                           invokeCommand.<fn>
    | dart:async                                                                               Future.Future.sync
    | /usr/local/sandbox/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/utils.dart 90                      syncFuture
    | /usr/local/sandbox/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/bin/pub.dart 197                           invokeCommand
    | /usr/local/sandbox/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/bin/pub.dart 87                            runPub.<fn>
    | dart:async                                                                               Future.Future.sync
    | /usr/local/sandbox/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/utils.dart 102                     captureErrors.<fn>
    | package:stack_trace/src/chain.dart 93                                                    Chain.capture
    | /usr/local/sandbox/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/utils.dart 116                     captureErrors
    | /usr/local/sandbox/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/bin/pub.dart 87                            runPub
    | /usr/local/sandbox/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/bin/pub.dart 74                            main.<fn>
    | dart:isolate                                                                             _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage
```

I'm confused as to why `pub build` needs to open an HttpServer connection... and if I understand the stack trace, it's trying to bind to 127.0.0.1 port 0? And OpenShift is not allowing this? Am I understanding this correctly? Any OpenShift or Dart experts have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like pub build uses an HTTP server to serve the files to itself in order to process them. It defaults to 127.0.0.1:0 to do this, which OpenShift won't allow. The fix is to either allow pub build to customize what ip/port it uses, or to make it so it doesn't use an HTTP server at all (which, if I understand this comment (https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/trunk/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/command/build.dart#79) correctly, might be the better option).

Comment: I think the wish feature of the Pub Team is not to use a HTTP server here, but the isolate library is still missing the required features for that. Maybe this is a good reason to do it: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16368 Maybe you also update your issue with the stack trace.